# How to match 2 dictionary in python with their keys?

Tags: python-2.7

Here are my 2 dictionaries :

```
dictName={5159:'Cube',1007455:'Subdivision Surface'}
dictObj={5159: 7,1007455: 2}
```

I would like to get as a result :

**Cube : 7,
Subdivision Surface : 2**

I can't figure how to achieve that with their keys.

Comment: May you want to vote one answer as excepted or replay on some answers if something helped? Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for k,v in dictName.iteritems():                                                                                                                                          
...    result[v] = dictObj[k]                                                                                                                                                    
...                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> result                                                                                                                                                                       
{'Cube': 7, 'Subdivision Surface': 2}                                                                                                                                            
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
dictName={5159:'Cube',1007455:'Subdivision Surface'}
dictObj={5159: 7,1007455: 2}

for k, v in dictName.items():
  if k in dictObj:
    print(f'{dictName[k]}: {dictObj[k]}')
```

and for Python 2 (after reading the question):

```
dictName={5159:'Cube',1007455:'Subdivision Surface'}
dictObj={5159: 7,1007455: 2}

for k, v in dictName.iteritems():
  if k in dictObj:
    print '%s : %s' % (dictName[k], dictObj[k])
```

..which will also catch any problems where the key is not mutual in both dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Its faster and easyer with list comprehension:

```
solution = {dictName[key_name]:dictObj[key_obj]
            for key_name in dictName.keys() for key_obj in dictObj.keys()
            if key_name == key_obj}
```

Update:
You need to check same names as well hence, the double list comprehension.